# Twilio for Window Phone 8 SDK

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, twilio

The latest version of Twilio REST API (3.5.6) doesn't support Window Phone 8.0 SDK.

Is it OK to use Twillio service through the Windows Azure?
Can anyone give me some sample, Thanks!

Comment: Windows Phone 8.0 SDK should be backward-compatible with older SDK (such as 7.1 & 7.1.1), therefore it should be okay to use Twillio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio can be used in multiple ways when working with Windows Azure. You can use it in Virtual Machines, Cloud Services, Web Sites and even Mobile Services.

Since you're building a WP8 application consider using Mobile Services: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/10/17/announcing-the-windows-azure-mobile-services-october-update.aspx